# laravel accessor very slow

Tags: php, laravel

and i have table called `journal_entries` and inside this table i have tow column

```
price
price_t
```

now if the person is admin i want him to see the price column
but if the person is not admin i want him to see price_t as price
and this is my accessor code

```
public function getTotalNetPriceAttribute()
{
    if(!Gate::allows('info'))
    {
        if(isset($this->attributes['total_net_price_t']))
        {
            if($this->attributes['total_net_price_t'] == null)
                return $this->attributes['total_net_price'];
            else
                return $this->attributes['total_net_price_t'];
        }
        if(isset($this->attributes['total_net_price']))
            return $this->attributes['total_net_price'];
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($this->attributes['total_net_price']))
            return $this->attributes['total_net_price'];
    }
}
```

now if the person is admin the code tack normal time like 1 to 2 min as treal balace in accunting its normal time but with the accessor if the user now admin its tack long long time
is there any way to speed it up
thanks ..

Comment: Nothing in this accessor would slow the function, but I suspect your Gate is querying the database to check the user's role on EVERY item that you want the price of.  See if there is a better way to implement this or cache the gate logic.

Comment: ill try to remove the gate and check with normal if like if (1 == 1) and see the result thanks for replay

Comment: yes its the gate slow the code very much how can i fix that its slow the code very very much

Comment: Do you need to check the gate for every item?  Can't you check it once at a higher level. If not then you need to cache the gate check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the gate file its working good now thanks for all